# Bash script does not allow to handover content to a variable, which is partly the counter of a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, variable-assignment

I need to replace temporary stored files by variables.
I call 6 files from a bitbucket repo and want to place each file content in an own variable.

```
# declare array for all files
declare -a file_array=("one.txt" "two.txt" "three.txt" "four.json" "five.txt" "six.txt")

for file in "${file_array[@]}"
do 
     echo "$file"
     "file_$file='$(curl -k -s -X GET -H "${var1}" -H "${var2}" "${var3}${var4}")'"

done
```

This code just gives me an error. It seems like it is always taking the content of the file as a command:

```
$'file_one.txt=\'<<file content>>'': command not found
```

Comment: You cannot have a dot in a variable name. So `file_one.txt` is not a valid variable name.

Comment: And you should use namerefs instead of trying to assign expressions like `file_$file`.

Comment: Or `declare file_$file=....` maybe

Comment: @Jetchisel Interestingly `declare "file_${file/./_}"=$(command)` seams to not work as expected if `command` returns several lines. While `declare -n f="file_${file/./_}"; f=$(command)` seams to be OK. I thought it was about the same... Apparently not.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, Never did that Parameter Expansion during the assignment with declare but, thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two problems here: you try to put a dot in a variable name, which is invalid, and you try to assign expressions. Plus your quoting which also looks strange.

You could use namerefs (`declare -n`) and substitute the dots, e.g., with underscores:

```
# declare array for all files
declare -a file_array=("one.txt" "two.txt" ...)

for file in "${file_array[@]}"; do 
  echo "$file"
  declare -n f="file_${file/./_}"
  f=$(curl -k -s -X GET -H "${var1}" -H "${var2}" "${var3}${var4}")
done
printf '%s\n' "$file_one_txt"
```

Comment: I want to handover 6 files to a variable, this is why there are the dots. your solution with declare seems to be working, thanks! nevertheless, I need to create 6 different variables inside the for loop. 
If I would use your solution above with f=$(curl...), I would overwrite f with every loop.
I tried this one:
c=0
for file in "${file_array[@]}";
do 
   declare -n f="file_${file/./_}"
   f[c]=$(curl ...)
   c=$(($c+1));
done
But it shows only in the first run of the loop the correct output...

Comment: "_If I would use your solution above with f=$(curl...), I would overwrite f with every loop_": no. Give it a try. `f` is a nameref. Its value is the real name of the bash variable that is assigned when you assign `f`. So, if you run the loop exactly as it is, you will have defined and assigned six **different** variables named `file_one_txt`, `file_two_txt`... Have a look, maybe, at the `bash` manual and search for `nameref`.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!! Fantastic... Now I need to learn about namerefs :-)

Comment: "_Now I need to learn about namerefs_": yeah, they're sometimes handy. Especially to pass a variable by name (instead of value) to a function. If you start using them remember that when you `unset` a nameref it is also the referenced variable that is really `unset`. In our small example, to `unset` variable `f`, we would use `unset -n f`.

Comment: I have the script in place and it works fine on my Ubuntu VM Workstation. But now next step is to run the script on an automated way on a remote AWS instance. Unfortunately, the Linux image there is not supporting declare -n... is there any alternative for this you are aware of? Thanks in advance!!